# pylucene install makefile error

Tags: python, makefile, pylucene

When I build the pylucene environment, I meet this problem.
I don't know how to config the makefile of it on Windows platform.
Someone help me, if there is any example about building pylucene on Windows.

The `cmd` shows that:

```
can not find tools.jar
makefile213:recipe for target 'ivy' failed.
make:***【ivy】error 1
```

Here is the makefile:

```
VERSION=3.6.1-2
LUCENE_SVN_VER=HEAD
LUCENE_VER=3.6.1
LUCENE_SVN=http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_6_1
PYLUCENE:=$(shell cd)
LUCENE_SRC=lucene-java-$(LUCENE_VER)
LUCENE=$(LUCENE_SRC)/lucene

# Windows   (Win32, Python 2.7, Java 1.6, ant 1.8.1, Java not on PATH)
SHELL=cmd.exe
PYLUCENE:=$(shell cd)
ANT=D:\ant183\bin\ant
JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_01
PREFIX_PYTHON=D:\\Python27
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)\python.exe
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc.__main__
NUM_FILES=3

$(LUCENE_JAR): $(LUCENE)
    cd $(LUCENE) && $(ANT) -Dversion=$(LUCENE_VER)
OS=$(shell uname)
BUILD_TEST:=$(PYLUCENE)\build\test
```

Comment: were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error when installing on opensuse 13.2, the way to work around is to install ivy independently before trying to build pylucene.

Comment: do you have the docker instructions for this ?

Comment: @Dreams the question is 8 years old and answer is 5 years old. I am not sure how relevant they are in the latest pylucene and OS's. Maybe it's worth checking https://hub.docker.com/r/coady/pylucene/Dockerfile.